# How to change value of all properties within a nested JSON object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to get a key/property from a JSON object and change all of its values, whether its nested within another object, or by itself.

I have a locale variable

```
const locale = "en"
```

and I'm trying to change the value of the returned json object depending on locale, such as

```
result.navTitle = result.navTitle[locale]

or

stories.map((story)=> story.navTitle = story.navTitle[locale]);
...etc
```

```
result = [
{
    "data":{
        "en":"English",
        "fi":"Finnish"
    },
    "navTitle":{
        "en":"English",
        "fi":"Finnish"
    },
    "stories": [
       {
        "navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"},
        "cards":[
            {
                "navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"}
            },
             {
                "navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"}
            }
        ]
       },
       {
        "navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"}
       }
    ]
}
]
```

I have managed to do this with repetitive .map functions but it gets long, is there any other alternative to do this?

Comment: Can you get a different set of JSON because that's kind of a mess of duplication. Ideally you want an object with the different locales as keys, and then you can add properties to those keys: `{ en: { title: 'English' }, fi: { title: 'Finnish } }` etc, and then you can just target the object key by locale and then extract the relevant values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function, say `getLocaleData()` to get the relevant data for each locale, adopting a recursive approach to selectively clone the input data.

Once we reach a child object with properties like 'en', 'fi' etc, we'll return only the property that matches the desired locale.

**Update:** I've added a default value, e.g. '' to return if the locale isn't present and demonstrated with an example. This should now leave non-localized objects as is.

```js
const result = [ { "data":{ "en":"English", "fi":"Finnish" }, features: {}, "navTitle":{ "en":"English", "fi":"Finnish" }, "stories": [ { "navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"}, "cards":[ { "navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"} }, { "navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"} } ] }, { "navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"} } ] } ]

function getLocaleData(obj, locale, defaultValue = '') {
    if (!obj) return obj;
    // If a property key is 'en', 'fi' etc, return the value.
    if (typeof(obj[locale]) === 'string') return obj[locale];
   
    if (Object.keys(obj).length > 0 && Object.keys(obj).every(k => k.length === 2)) { 
        return defaultValue;
    }

    let result = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {};
    for (let k in obj) {
        result[k] = (typeof(obj[k]) === "object") ? getLocaleData(obj[k], locale, defaultValue): obj[k];
    }
    return result;
}

console.log('\nEnglish data:', getLocaleData(result, 'en'));
console.log('\nFinnish data:', getLocaleData(result, 'fi'))

// This locale doesn't exist
console.log('\nGerman data:', getLocaleData(result, 'de', ''))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How is it possible to make this work even though if the object doesn't have both "en" and "fi", only one for example.

Currently passing a locale that doesnt exist gives this
"navTitle": { "en": "English" } but making it that passing "fi" to the getlocaleDate, you would get "navTitle": { } or { "fi": '" " }

Comment: I'm sure one could modify to give that result... I'll update when I get a chance!

Comment: I've added a default value, e.g. '' to return if the locale isn't present and demonstrated with an example.

Comment: This kinda does the trick, but at the same time affecting other properties, for example if i have a property createdAt: {}, or facilities:[], it will change those as well to a
string ' ' regardles if they have "en", or "fi"

Comment: I've updated again. I'll only return the default string if the object is a locale-lookup value (all keys have length 2). One could enhance to make sure all keys are valid iso locales.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion,.

Basically just check if array of object, if array simply map, if it's an object you can use Object.entries / fromEntries to change, inside the loop of the Object.entries you can then test for the lang, if the values of the entries are an object, just pass this to itself for the recursion bit.

Example below..

```js
const result = [{"data":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"},"navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"},"stories":[{"navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"},"cards":[{"navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"}},{"navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"}}]},{"navTitle":{"en":"English","fi":"Finnish"}}]}];

function langObj(lang, obj) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      return obj.map(m => langObj(lang, m));
    } else {
      return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v]) => {
          const x = v[lang] || v;
          return [k, langObj(lang, x)];
        })
      );
    }
  } else {
    return obj;
  }
}

console.log('English');
console.log(langObj('en', result));
console.log('Finnish');
console.log(langObj('fi', result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) that might be a bit easier to reason about.

Note that this solution modifies the result object and does not make a copy. If this is undesired it should be cloned before hand (using eg lodash).

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.1.2/lib/index.min.js';

const result = [{ data: { en: 'English', fi: 'Finnish' }, navTitle: { en: 'English', fi: 'Finnish' }, stories: [{ navTitle: { en: 'English', fi: 'Finnish' }, cards: [{ navTitle: { en: 'English', fi: 'Finnish' } }, { navTitle: { en: 'English', fi: 'Finnish' } }] }, { navTitle: { en: 'English', fi: 'Finnish' } }] }];

const rewrite = (data, language) => {
  objectScan([`**.${language}`], {
    filterFn: ({ gparent, gproperty, value }) => {
      if (typeof value === 'string') {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        gparent[gproperty] = value;
      }
    }
  })(data);
};

rewrite(result, 'en');

console.log(result);
// => [ { data: 'English', navTitle: 'English', stories: [ { navTitle: 'English', cards: [ { navTitle: 'English' }, { navTitle: 'English' } ] }, { navTitle: 'English' } ] } ]
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)